# How to generate static pages with nested dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, next.js, static-site-generation

I have been working on this site and I have hit a wall. Basically I am supposed to list movies by genre, fetched from database. The genre should take me to another list based on the genre. Once a user clicks the movie from say 'action' genre it takes them to the movie details on another page.
This is the structure

```
Movies/ [moviesbygenrelist]/list
```

Everything works till there.

Moving on to the second dynamic page I cannot get values of first and second dynamic page
as below...

```
Movies/ [moviesbygenrelist]/[movie-slug]
```

I am statically generating the site

how can i get parameters of first page while on the second dynamic page

This is what i have,
I first call

```
 let movieTypeID;
 let movieSlug;
    export async function getStaticProps({params}) {

        movieTypeID=params.movietype;
        movieSlug=params.movie;


     }
```

my logic is i can access route parameters from getStaticProps but not in getStaticPaths so I call it first, instantiate the variables then pass them to getStaticPaths so I can make database calls using the variables since I am now a bit deep in the database. I cannot make calls without the dynamic parameters
I pass them like below

```
export async function getStaticPaths(movieTypeID, movieSlug) {

///only they come out as undefined


 }
```

Comment: For pages with dynamic routes, [`getStaticPaths` is what defines the list of paths used in `getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation) at built time, and not the other way around.

Comment: As it is i cannot query the paths since i dont have the two parameters. From this part in documentation,, pages/posts/[postId]/[commentId]  user sees list of posts clicks post1 which moves to postscomments page. but in order to prerender the comments page I'll need post1(the id). How will getStaticPaths get these id

Comment: See the difference in application from this,,, pages/posts/[id].js which is the only type of example the documentation gives. Which one fetches and prerenders posts and their ids only

Comment: You can retrieve the ids by querying the database in `getStaticPaths` and generate the paths list.

Comment: How do i know what post to get the comments for. That is the question. Is it post1, post2,,, which one? and where do i pass this postID to getStaticPaths function while on the comments page

Comment: Remember that you're statically generating these pages. You have to generate paths for all existing posts and comments in `getStaticPaths`, so iterate over all posts, and all comments for each post.

Comment: Then i must be ordering my pages wrong or something. Can you provide an example as an answer, kindly. Using this example ... pages/posts/[postId]/[commentId] . Write a mock database query in
getStaticPaths for list of posts for the first page(postsId) and a query in getStaticPaths for second page (comments)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the page is located under `pages/movies/[type]/[slug].jsx` in your Next.js app:

```js
// pages/movies/[type]/[slug].jsx
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const movies = db.getAllMovies() // Retrieve all movies data from database
  const paths = movies.map((movie) => ({
    params: { type: movie.type, slug: movie.slug },
  }))

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false // Paths not returned will result in a 404
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { type, slug } = params
  const movieData = getMovie(type, slug) // Retrieve data for given type/slug pair

  return {
    props: {
      data: movieData
    }
  }
}

function Movie({ data }) {
  //render the given movie data
}

export default Movie
```

This will statically generate pages for all movies in your database. Each page will be available at `/movies/<movie-type>/<movie-slug>` in the browser.

Comment: Ooh I guess this makes sense. I'll try to implement this  according to my database (firestore) and get back. This method looks really expensive and complex from the database structure i have but it makes sense

Comment: Is there a way to use 2 `params` properties, but with same slug? In this example, I'd need type for different api calls, but I need route to have only `/slug`, not `/type/slug`

Comment: That's not possible with the same slug. You could look into [catch-all dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes) to have one page handle all routing, but you'd still need something like `/type/slug` for multiple params to be passed.