# React Next.js and DatoCMS with nested slugs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I’m building my site structure in React and DatoCMS like this:

projects/project-category/project-detail

And this is my query:

```
allProjects {
    slug
    projectCategoryParent {
      slug
    }
    genericPageParent {
      slug
    }
}
```

…can someone please point me in the right direction showing how to use getStaticPaths and getStaticProps in such a way that Project pages can be reached by joining all of the slugs together?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this help answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65553115/1870780?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that's got the content loading on the Project detail page.

How do I use the same method to load content on the Project Category page?

I can see that using an index.js file is the way forward but I cannot access the correct props.

Comment: All sorted now!

Using a first level dynamic folder [category] with category.js; and a second level dynamic folder [project] and project.js

Then params: { category: content.slug } and params: { category: content.projectCategoryParent.projectcategory, project: content.slug } respectively to query the relevant slugs.