# How to map from API call to params in getStaticPaths?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to map params into Next.js `getStaticPaths` but it doesn't work. Below you can see it works.

[image]

But it doesn't work as soon as want to add one more field which is the slug of the article.

The routing looks something like this. `index>[username]>[slug]` <=== slug is for article.

To simplify the code, the API looks like this.

```
[
 {
  id
  username
  email
 },
 articles: [
   [Object], [Object], [Object],
  ]
 }
]
```

And inside articles array looks something like this:

```
articles: [
 {
  id
  title
  description
  slug
 }
]
```

How do I make it work? How to map username and article's slug to param so that it works?

Edit: I want to have username slug and article slug together so that I can have `www.com/[username]/[articleSlug]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to generate static pages with nested dynamic routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65550644/how-to-generate-static-pages-with-nested-dynamic-routes)? You need to pass both `username` _and_ `slug` in the params objects inside your `getStaticPaths`.

Comment: Also, please add your code as a snippet, do _not_ use images for code.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understood your issue very well, but you just use `getStaticPaths` to generate the article url like this:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const articles = await fetchAPI("/articles")

  return {
    paths: articles.map((article) => ({
      params: {
        slug: article.slug,
      },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  }
}
```

Then to get the user and the article data you can use `getStaticProps` like this:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const article = (await fetchAPI(`/articles?slug=${params.slug}`))[0]
  const users = await fetchAPI("/users")

  return {
    props: { article, users },
    revalidate: 1,
  }
}
```

Comment: I have no problem getting the params… but when I try to add one more param it becomes a problem. This page is a dynamic page with dynamic url. The url is www.[username]/[articleSlug] so adding just the article url won’t be enough, I need the username param too.

Comment: You should do that in the username page then in the same way we've done for articles above. Son when you got to www.[username] you will see username info in that page. If you go to www.[username]/[articleSlug] you'll see the article info in there. This is how it works in next.js, if you don't need a page for username then you can just append it at the end with ?username='Jon' This will point you in the right direction https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes - please upvote if this was of a help for you :)

Comment: I have that configured in my username page already. It’s working perfectly fine whenever I browse www.[username] but now I want to have an article that’s linked to a profile like so [username]/[articleSlug] but to do that I need to have my folders configured like so: pages/[username]/[slug] username folder has index.jsx which represents [username] param whereas [slug] folder is a child folder of username and that’s also with index.jsx which represents [slug]. I can’t have username page have username param and not slug page not have it too, it has to be consistent otherwise I’ll get an error.

Comment: how does this looks on your folder tree?

Comment: Edited my comment after your latest comment. Please have a look at above.